# How can I pass the object associated with rating in semantic-ui?

Tags: semantic-ui

Currently I have star ratings for all my objects in this:

```
<div class="ui star rating" data-rating="0" data-max-rating="5"></div>
```

In my js file

```
$('.ui.rating')
.rating('setting', 'onRate', function(value) {  
});
```

I am able to retrieve the value of the new star rating. In the function code, I'll like to redirect to a link which will save this rating such as

```
window.location.href = '/update/item/{id}/value/{value};
```

How would I get the item.id that the star rating falls upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you bind your `id` value to the rating when rendered using a `data-` attribute (say `data-id`), which can then be accessed when a new rating is selected.

```js
$('.ui.rating').rating('setting', 'onRate', function(value) {
  var url = '/update/item/' + $(this).data('id') + '/value/' + value;
  $('#href').text(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

101: <div class="ui star rating" data-id="101" data-rating="0" data-max-rating="5"></div><br />
102: <div class="ui star rating" data-id="102" data-rating="0" data-max-rating="5"></div><br />
window.location.href = "<span id="href"></span>";
```